Plasma charge conservation for a multi-Euler system - looking for quasi-linear Riemann solver that also resolves slow contact discontinuity
I am solving a multi-species plasma problem by assigning a set of ideal gas Euler equations to each species, e.g. protons and electrons.
I.e. I am solving the system
$$
\partial_tU_s + \partial_x(F_s) = S_s
$$
with
$$
U=(\rho_s, \rho_s u_s, E_s)^T,\;\;F=(\rho_s u_s, \rho_s u_s^2 + P_s, v_s(E_s+P_s))^T
$$
and the source term
$$  S_s=(0, -\rho_s\nabla \Phi, -\rho_s u_s \nabla \Phi)
$$
where $(\rho_s, u_s, P_s)$ are the hydrodynamic primitives, $(\rho_s,\rho_s u_s, \frac{1}{2}\rho_s u_s^2 + \rho_s e_s)$ are the conserved hydro variables, $\Phi$ is a gravitational potential function, and $n_s=\rho_s/m_s$ are the number densities of each species.
Naively, if the $u_s$ are equal, then the ratio of number densities for one species relative to one another $n_s/n_s'$ should be conserved throughout the hydro step, throughout the simulation domain.
This would guarantee e.g. charge conservation.
Now the strategy to solve this system is to solve each species individually with the HLLC solver, well-balance against gravity and apply a number of other operators later.
Now the HLLC's first flux component in the mass equation
$$ F^{HLLC}_{i+1/2} = (F_0, F_1, F_2)^T \\
F_0 \propto (\rho_s u_s) + \rho_s(u_s+c_s)(\frac{c_s}{u_r+c_s -s_*}-1)
$$
has a dependency on the pressure and sound-speeds via the second term on the r.h.s, which breaks the property that all species are advected with just the flux $\rho_s u_s$. This changes the relative numbers $n_s/n_s'$ after one timestep.
This is the root cause why my electron+proton numbers are not conserved, even if I enforce an identical velocity throughout the domain.
I want to also distinguish this from multicomponent Euler systems, which is not what I am solving here (e.g. as spelled out in detail in this question). In my version, the species' different velocities w.r.t each other are supposed to allow for currents.
Additionally, any Riemann-solver I employ needs to resolve slowly moving contact waves, which help well-balance against gravity.
I was wondering what other, simpler, possibly linear Riemann solver I could use, while meeting my charge conservation+contact wave requirements? I've tried the Lax-Friedrich flux, and confirmed that this conserves charges after the transport step, but the LF flux produces negative pressures in other parts of the domain, and is anyway just used as indicator that the mass advection is the problem here.
I'd be happy for any ideas how to resolve this with a different Riemann solver / Flux. My incling is that Roe should work for this, but I don't have a solver ready for it just now.

Can you write down the equation system which is discretized and solved?

@ConvexHull Good point, done.

I am not able to follow your explanations. If you use the same velocity field, the ratio of number densities will still change. Even a Roe or exact flux approximation won't fix this.

Are you saying you specify that the velocity field are equal for all time (somehow)? Or are you initializing the same velocity field and allowing them to evolve however according to the PDE? If the latter there should be no expectation that the velocity fields of the two species remains the same.

@helloworld922: I have a friction operator tying the velocity fields together in a part of the simulation domain, and not others. But whatever solver I am using, it has to fulfil the case that if all v's are identical, then numbers must be conserved.

@ConvexHull So the question then is, what do I do to keep my numbers conserved nonetheless?

@AtmosphericPrisonEscape Let me ask you some more questions. With charge-conservation you are talking about a quasi-neutral Plasma $n_e = Z_i n_i$?

@ConvexHull Indeed. This would be trivially guaranteed, if the mass flux for all species' would be identical to $\rho_s u_s$, but due to the structure of the hydrodynamic system, you get additional terms into the numerical fluxes.

Sure however, this is only guaranted for an exact solution of each system. In an incompressible Eulerian framework the quasi-neutrality would always be locally violated due to numerical diffusion or dispersion. Moreover, since you are using a compressible Eulerian framework for each species, quasi-neutrality would also be violated due to physical reasons. You already mentioned the dependancy on thermodynamic quantities, e.g. speed of sound. On the other hand, charge-conservation is always garanted in a global sense, because each  species is by definition conservative.

Are you familiar with Lagrangian methods or at least Eulerian models which are generally used in the multi-fluid community? I have the feeling that your system is not even well posed.

@ConvecHull Not very, hence my asking here. I'd be grateful for references. How would it be ill-posed, I am sure I've seen this type of system used in plasma physics before.

Perhaps, as original OP, you may share a reference to the "whole" system. Generally when using a (diffuse) multi-fluid approach one performs an ensemble average prior to both systems in order to derive equations including relaxation parameters for temperature, pressure or velocity equilibrium, so called 7, 6 or 5 equation models. Anyway, as already said, your goal is rather local quasi-neutrality and less charge conservation. A sharp interface approach may be a further option. Apart from that, I currently don't see how you can derive your goal.

They are Schunk&Nagy's 5-moment equations. I didn't include all terms (e.g. momentum and temperature exchange), as they are not relevant for the charge problem. Haven't heard about sharp interfaces, feel free to recommend literature.

So your equations are in the Boltzmann limit, thank you for the reference. Sharp-Interface methods are level-set-based and often combined with immersed boundary methods. Often they are applied to moving contact lines, e.g, for multiphase flows. But I do not think these methods fit to your problem. Another option would be to reduce the numerical diffusion with high-resolution schemes or limiters, you are using FV I guess? However, be aware that due to your compressible framework, violation of quasi-neutrality is somehow physical. I think you have to rethink what you actually want to achieve.

I see, no those methods don't fit, as there are no phase boundaries, my gases all share the same volume. Yeah I am using FV (HLLC is a popular Riemann solver), so numerical diffusion is already at its minimum. Yeah I am coming to realize how that it's physical and a problem.
